# How can i avoid making two tkinter windows?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I have made a GUI in which on user values a line is drawn, and when you click on the line another window opens where you can select something. And when you press ok it should print on the terminal. I think because i am creating a new tkinter window when i click on the line, i am unable to retrieve the user selection.How can i solve this problem? Your help is greatly appreciated.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib import style
import tkinter as tk    
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
import random
import numpy as np

    
LARGE_FONT = ('Verdana',12)
style.use('ggplot')

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt    


class PageOne(tk.Tk):
    
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        label = tk.Label(self,text='Experiment', font = LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        
        self.adding_widgets()

        button2= ttk.Button(self,text='Validate', command=self.draw)
        button2.pack()

        button3= ttk.Button(self,text='Erase', command=self.dlet)
        button3.pack()


        self.lines_pts=[] 
        
        self.f1= Figure(figsize=(5,5),dpi=100)
        self.b=self.f1.add_subplot(1,1,1)
        self.b.set_xlim([0,10])
        self.b.set_ylim([0,10])  
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.f1, self)
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP,fill=tk.BOTH,expand=True)
        self.f1.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', self.on_pick)

        
        self.lines =[]
        


    def adding_widgets(self,*args):
        labfram=ttk.LabelFrame(self,width=100,height=100,text='Enter Member Coordinates',labelanchor=N)
        labfram.pack()
        

        l1=ttk.Label(labfram,text='x0')
        l1.pack(side='left')
        self.x0=Entry(labfram,width=10,)
        self.x0.pack(side='left')


        l2=ttk.Label(labfram,text='y0')
        l2.pack(side='left')
        self.y0=Entry(labfram,width=10)
        self.y0.pack(side='left')


        l3=ttk.Label(labfram,text='x1')
        l3.pack(side='left')
        self.x1=Entry(labfram,width=10)
        self.x1.pack(side='left')


        l4=ttk.Label(labfram,text='y1')
        l4.pack(side='left')
        self.y1=Entry(labfram,width=10)
        self.y1.pack(side='left')
        
            
    def draw(self):
        
        p0 = float(self.x0.get()), float(self.y0.get())
        p1 = float(self.x1.get()), float(self.y1.get())
        self.lines_pts.append((p0,p1))

        for p0,p1 in self.lines_pts:
            x0, y0, x1, y1 = *p0, *p1
            X = x0,x1
            Y = y0,y1
        
        ax = self.b.plot(X,Y, 'r', linewidth=4,picker=5 )
        
        self.lines.append(ax) 
        self.canvas.draw() 

    
    def dlet(self):
        self.b.lines.remove(self.b.lines[-1])
        self.canvas.draw()

    
    def on_pick(self,event):
        w=Tk()
        w.title('Channel Select')
        w.geometry('250x50')

        n = StringVar() 
        ch = ttk.Combobox(w, width = 15 , textvariable = n)
        ch['values'] = ('CH1','CH2','CH3','CH4','CH5','CH6','CH7','CH8','CH9','CH10')
        ch.grid(column=1,row=0)
        ch_label = ttk.Label(w,text='Select Your Channel')
        ch_label.grid(column=0,row=0)
        ch_button = ttk.Button(w,text='OK',command=lambda: print ('value is:'+ n.get()))
        ch_button.grid(column=1,row=1)



        for line in self.lines:
            line = event.artist
        xdata, ydata = line.get_data()
        ind = event.ind
        print('on pick line:', np.array([xdata[ind], ydata[ind]]).T)



app = PageOne()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's here do you really want to create a new window?

```
def on_pick(self,event):
    w=Tk()
    w.title('Channel Select')
    w.geometry('250x50')
```

Take note that when you do this `w=Tk()` you are creating an instance of an object a **NEW OBJECT** which is Tk() so that's why it creates a new window.  What is your goal are you really trying to pop up a window whenever you click cause if not you I think you can remove this.

***----UPDATE---***

So the reason why your window keeps popping out is because on your function you create an instance of an object with it. Then I tried putting the `w=Tk()` away from the function but still it would create or show that object cause it is within the `mainloop`.

Alternative solution is you can check if once that window exists or its state is **normal** then you can just do a `focus`.

Here is the code that I've added only on your `on_pick` function. I also added on your `__init__` method a `self.w = None` to just set the w variable to None initially.

**OVERALL this are only the changes made**

```
def on_pick(self,event):

        try:
            if self.w.state() == "normal":
                self.w.focus()

        except BaseException as on_pick_error:
            self.w=Toplevel()
            self.w.title('Channel Select')
            self.w.geometry('250x50')

            n = StringVar() 
            ch = ttk.Combobox(self.w, width = 15 , textvariable = n)
            ch['values'] = ('CH1','CH2','CH3','CH4','CH5','CH6','CH7','CH8','CH9','CH10')
            ch.grid(column=1,row=0)
            ch_label = ttk.Label(self.w,text='Select Your Channel')
            ch_label.grid(column=0,row=0)
            ch_button = ttk.Button(self.w,text='OK',command=lambda: print ('value is:'+ n.get()))
            ch_button.grid(column=1,row=1)



            for line in self.lines:
                line = event.artist
            xdata, ydata = line.get_data()
            ind = event.ind
            print('on pick line:', np.array([xdata[ind], ydata[ind]]).T)
```

You might wonder what this does, it just checks if the state of your `self.w` which happens to be your window that pops out, it just checks if its state is equal to **"normal"** meaning that it is active, then when it is it will just do a `.focus()` and focus on that current window. Else it would create a new window which is this `self.w=Toplevel()` and so on.

```
try:
    if self.w.state() == "normal":
        self.w.focus()

except BaseException as on_pick_error:
    self.w=Toplevel()
    self.w.title('Channel Select')
    self.w.geometry('250x50')
```

**Why is it Toplevel instead of Tk?**

I would suggest to have it Toplevel however it is up to you to decide since Toplevel and Tk I think might just have the same properties but do note they are not the same so it's up to you.

Comment: My ultimate goal is to label the line drawn by the user selection. So i thought of creating a combobox where user can select and based on the selection i can put the user selection near the line. (still to figure out) I thought maybe this is how i could do it.

Comment: on your `__init__` method don't forget to put `self.w = None` just to initialize. Cool application by the way... I like the way it draws the line.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, yes indeed it works! but after looking it up i also now think that toplevel is the right way to go about it. The thing is at times i want to do something but because this is my first gui application and i am new to OOP at times i am bit lost. Thanks for the help and i am glad somebody likes my app!

Comment: No problem! yes It's cool! I love the way it draws the line! Glad I could help :)

Comment: it also works the same way if i declare self.w=Toplevel(), it is necessary to do do a try and except statement ?

Comment: Yes , the purpose of the `try and except` is for example when the window is not `active` you're calling the function `.state()` and that function would give an error to `self.w` since it is initially set to `None` and a `None` type does not have a `.state()` function so just to covert it up.